# ejabberd: AccessRules: Account does not have the right to perform the operation

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I'm trying to follow [API Permissions | ejabberd Docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/permissions/#examples-of-who-rules) and [Configuring ejabberd | ejabberd Docs](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#access-rules).

yet while trying to register a user:

```
# curl -sk -d '{"user":"test", "password":"testing", "host":"localhost"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://localhost:5443/api/register
```

I get following in `ejabberd.log`:

```
# tail -2 ./home/ejabberd/logs/ejabberd.log 
2019-10-04 21:41:47.079 [info] <0.663.0>@mod_http_api:log:509 API call register [{<<"user">>,<<"test">>},{<<"password">>,<<"testing">>},{<<"host">>,<<"localhost">>}] from ::ffff:172.19.0.1:53740
2019-10-04 21:41:47.079 [info] <0.521.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:256 (<0.663.0>) Accepted connection [::ffff:172.19.0.1]:53740 -> [::ffff:172.19.0.6]:5443
#
```

`ejabberd.yml`' `acl`&`api_permissions` blocks:

```
acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"
    ip:
      - ::/0
      - ::FFFF:10.0.0.0/8
      - ::FFFF:172.16.0.0/12
      - ::FFFF:172.19.0.0/12
      - ::FFFF:192.168.0.0/16
```

&

```
api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who: 
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
          ip:
            - ::/0
            - ::FFFF:10.0.0.0/8
            - ::FFFF:172.16.0.0/12
            - ::FFFF:172.19.0.0/12
            - ::FFFF:192.168.0.0/16
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added my `ip`/range to `admin` *AND* `loopback` block:

```
acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
      - ::FFFF:172.19.0.0/16
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"
    ip:
      - ::FFFF:172.19.0.0/16
```

and the error went away)

Answer (score 0):

With this minimal configuration:

```
listen:
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/api": mod_http_api

acl:
  admin:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.1"

api_permissions:
  "admin commands":
    who: admin
    what:
      - register
```

If I execute this in machine 127.0.0.1, it works:

```
$ curl -sk -d '{"user":"test", "password":"testing", "host":"localhost"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://localhost:5443/api/register

"User test@localhost successfully registered"
```

Comment: If this question is solved, mark it as solved. Once this is solved, I will put attention in the new one.

Comment: thanks for putting your attention into my question(s), I really do appreciate that! now, is my question solved? not quite... the closest I ever got to question being solved is when I got rid of `api_permissions`' `admin access`: `who` block and replaced it with `who: all`, but I'm not exactly happy w/ result as I'm unable to limit networks (where are requests are coming from (not leaving it wide open for internet))

Comment: The small example that I provided limits registration to allow it only for the IP 127.0.0.1. Did you try that example? Does it work as designed? If yes, then you can add a few more ip lines with the networks that you want to allow, right?